# Исключить строки ячейки которой есть в другой таблице

Tags: php, mysql

Очень сложно сформулировать заголовок так чтобы описать им всю суть, поэтому начну с начала:
Есть некий сайт ([даже показать могу](http://jackrv.pp.ua)), как видно в нем выводятся блоки с данными, необходимо добавить возможность скрытия определенных блоков самими пользователями.
Для это я создал новую таблицу в которую заношу всего два параметра, уникальный ID номер текущего пользователя и такой же номер пользователя чей блок намереваются скрыть. Т.е. одна запись - одно исключение
Теперь нужно как то составить запрос на выборку всех пользователей, но если во второй таблице есть исключения - то исключить их из показа.
Я конечно могу это сделать средствами непосредственно PHP, но хотелось бы решение покрасивше и поаккуратнее найти.

Кстати, если есть другие предложения по реализации этой затеи - буду рад слышать!

Comment: Тег "исключения" тут лишний, он подразумевает Exception.

Comment: @jackrv покажите таблицы, сделайте пример данных на http://sqlfiddle.com/ а вообще вам наверное поможет [мой предыдущий ответ](/questions/286379/) (смотрите там SELECT)

Comment: Очень долго искал где же на этом сайте заветная кнопочка "сформировать ссылку"..
Смотрите, вот я создал минимальную таблицу (две если быть точным). Задача такова: если заходит пользователь 76561198077316950, то ему нужно вывести все записи исключая первые 6 (именно сколько он отметил "прочитанными").
Спасибо за ответ, пойду теперь разбираться с вашим советом...
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5e029

Comment: @eicto так у меня и не вышло сопоставить ваш ответ в той теме с моими данными :(

Comment: Это у вас реальная база такая? Или вы просто для примера структуру привели?

Смущает VARCHAR на числах и отсутствие индексов

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5e029/27

    SELECT users.id,users.steam_id FROM users LEFT JOIN ignore_list ON steam_id=to_id AND  from_id='76561198077316950' where isnull(to_id);

Comment: @eicto, isnull(to_id) работает быстрее чем to_id IS NULL ? И намного?

Comment: я про is null подзабыл, насчет что быстрее.... даж не знаю, про SQL пишут что **is null** быстрее, про mysql непонятно.

Comment: @eicto, одинаково.

Comment: @KiTE, аргументы ? на SO вот пишут что нет.

Comment: @eicto, я больше склонен доверять оптимизатору запросов. А он меняет `abc IS NULL` на `ISNULL(abc)`.

Comment: @BOPOH, малознаком со всем этим, вот и было так много подобных ошибок.
VARCHAR использовал т.к. int(18) не проходило, после вашего поста решил исправить сию ситуацию и понял что выхожу за рамки простого int, перешел на bigint
Индексы, на что их цеплять в данной таблице? Того что поле ID имеет primary key не достаточно?
Хотя можно сделать для steam_id такие записи уникальны, только вот какой индекс использовать и как его потом использовать?

Comment: Выборку вы будете проводить по from_id и to_id.

Поэтому я бы сделал покрывающий индекс по (from_id, to_id).

И зачем вообще в таблице игнора использовать id? Одного индекса на (from_id, to_id) разве не хватит?

Ладно бы если бы вы на эту таблицу как-то ссылались, но ведь все действия по ней будут - проверка заблокирован пользователь или нет и получение списка id заблокированных мною пользователей.

Т.е. по from_id и to_id вы однозначно идентифицируете запись. Поскольку числа целые, то индекс не будет таким уж и большим.

Удаление соответственно будет сразу по двум полям.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Будь у вас не интервалы, а простой список игнорируемых id, подошел бы второй вариант в левой колонке:

[image]

*UPD. Неправильно понял вопрос, так как был введен в заблуждение названием полей from_id и to_id, а также собственно названием таблицы: ignore_list. Однако оставлю-ка на всякий случай вариант решения, как если бы речь шла об интервалах.*

Но с этими интервалами все, мягко скажем, интереснее. Намечается проблема при росте хотя бы одной из таблиц - есть потребность связать все данные одной таблицы со всеми данными другой, а потом - сопоставить.

Логика здесь следующая: на первом этапе найти все те id, которые попадают хотя бы в один список (это будет вложенный запрос на выборку). На втором этапе выбрать только те записи, которые не вошли в ваш первый список. Выглядит это примерно так:

```
SELECT u.steam_id
  FROM users AS u
 WHERE u.steam_id NOT IN (SELECT u.steam_id
                           FROM users AS u,
                                ignore_list AS i
                          WHERE (u.steam_id >= i.from_id AND u.steam_id <= to_id))
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5e029/24/0).

Comment: Кто-то из нас не совсем правильно понял смысл вопроса.

Какие интервалы? Где про это сказано?

from_id - это id того, кто хочет отписаться от пользователя
to_id - это id того, от кого пользователь хочет отписаться

Т.е. достаточно использовать второй вариант левой колонки.

Comment: Да уж... Добавил комментарий в ответ.

Comment: @Denis Khvorostin, большое спасибо за ответ и за картинку в частности, будем курить это дело...

Answer (score 0):

Можно так:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE steam_id NOT IN (
    SELECT to_id
    FROM ignore_list
    WHERE from_id = '76561198077316950'
)
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5e029/8/0)

Comment: @KiTE ну я тоже померил на больших данных - получается одинаково, с другой стороны, если данных много то сама такая задача не очень хороша, т.к. приходится выбирать все строки из users и из ignore_list, что  в случае с join что в вашем ответе, просто join мне кажется выглядит немного лучше

Comment: @eicto, @KiTE, спасибо вам, будем разбираться, в песочнице работает а на практике будем тренироваться...